# Network output not working in LUA script -- Conky

Tags: networking, lua, conky

For those familiar with **Conky**, this should make a bit more sense.

I am trying to get the following Lua script to actually display its values for the 'NET' ring. I know that the code works outside of the script in **Conky** itself because running `conky -t '${downspeedf wlan0}'` outputs an acceptable value. I also know that the `conky_parse` bit in the code below works because all of the other rings are running fine. Why isn't it outputting the values either as numbers (in the center of the ring) or as a ring itself?

(I cut some unrelated stuff out so that the question would fit.)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                              draw_gauge_ring
-- display gauges
--
function draw_gauge_ring(data)
    local value = data.value
    local value_max = data.value_max
    local x, y = data.x, data.y
    local graph_radius = data.graph_radius
    local graph_thickness, graph_unit_thickness = data.graph_thickness, data.graph_unit_thickness
    local graph_start_angle = data.graph_start_angle
    local graph_unit_angle = data.graph_unit_angle
    local graph_bg_colour, graph_bg_alpha = data.graph_bg_colour, data.graph_bg_alpha
    local graph_fg_colour, graph_fg_alpha = data.graph_fg_colour, data.graph_fg_alpha
    local hand_fg_colour, hand_fg_alpha = data.hand_fg_colour, data.hand_fg_alpha
    local graph_end_angle = (value_max * graph_unit_angle) % 360

    if value == nil then value=0  end

    -- background ring
    cairo_arc(cr, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, 0), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, graph_end_angle))
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, rgb_to_r_g_b(graph_bg_colour, graph_bg_alpha))
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, graph_thickness)
    cairo_stroke(cr)

    -- arc of value
    local val = value % (value_max + 1)
    local start_arc = 0
    local stop_arc = 0
    local i = 1
    while i <= val do
        start_arc = (graph_unit_angle * i) - graph_unit_thickness
        stop_arc = (graph_unit_angle * i)
        cairo_arc(cr, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
        cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, rgb_to_r_g_b(graph_fg_colour, graph_fg_alpha))
        cairo_stroke(cr)
        i = i + 1
    end
    local angle = start_arc

    -- hand
    start_arc = (graph_unit_angle * val) - (graph_unit_thickness * 2)
    stop_arc = (graph_unit_angle * val)
    cairo_arc(cr, x, y, graph_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, rgb_to_r_g_b(hand_fg_colour, hand_fg_alpha))
    cairo_stroke(cr)

    -- graduations marks
    local graduation_radius = data.graduation_radius
    local graduation_thickness, graduation_mark_thickness = data.graduation_thickness, data.graduation_mark_thickness
    local graduation_unit_angle = data.graduation_unit_angle
    local graduation_fg_colour, graduation_fg_alpha = data.graduation_fg_colour, data.graduation_fg_alpha
    if graduation_radius > 0 and graduation_thickness > 0 and graduation_unit_angle > 0 then
        local nb_graduation = graph_end_angle / graduation_unit_angle
        local i = 0
        while i < nb_graduation do
            cairo_set_line_width(cr, graduation_thickness)
            start_arc = (graduation_unit_angle * i) - (graduation_mark_thickness / 2)
            stop_arc = (graduation_unit_angle * i) + (graduation_mark_thickness / 2)
            cairo_arc(cr, x, y, graduation_radius, angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, start_arc), angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, stop_arc))
            cairo_set_source_rgba(cr,rgb_to_r_g_b(graduation_fg_colour,graduation_fg_alpha))
            cairo_stroke(cr)
            cairo_set_line_width(cr, graph_thickness)
            i = i + 1
        end
    end

    -- text
    local txt_radius = data.txt_radius
    local txt_weight, txt_size = data.txt_weight, data.txt_size
    local txt_fg_colour, txt_fg_alpha = data.txt_fg_colour, data.txt_fg_alpha
    local movex = txt_radius * math.cos(angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, angle))
    local movey = txt_radius * math.sin(angle_to_position(graph_start_angle, angle))
    cairo_select_font_face (cr, "ubuntu", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, txt_weight)
    cairo_set_font_size (cr, txt_size)
    cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, rgb_to_r_g_b(txt_fg_colour, txt_fg_alpha))
    cairo_move_to (cr, x + movex - (txt_size / 2), y + movey + 3)
    cairo_show_text (cr, value)
    cairo_stroke (cr)

    -- caption
    local caption = data.caption
    local caption_weight, caption_size = data.caption_weight, data.caption_size
    local caption_fg_colour, caption_fg_alpha = data.caption_fg_colour, data.caption_fg_alpha
    local tox = graph_radius * (math.cos((graph_start_angle * 2 * math.pi / 360)-(math.pi/2)))
    local toy = graph_radius * (math.sin((graph_start_angle * 2 * math.pi / 360)-(math.pi/2)))
    cairo_select_font_face (cr, "ubuntu", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, caption_weight);
    cairo_set_font_size (cr, caption_size)
    cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, rgb_to_r_g_b(caption_fg_colour, caption_fg_alpha))
    cairo_move_to (cr, x + tox + 5, y + toy + 3)
    -- bad hack but not enough time !
    if graph_start_angle < 105 then
        cairo_move_to (cr, x + tox - 30, y + toy + 1)
    end
    cairo_show_text (cr, caption)
    cairo_stroke (cr)
end

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                    draw_ring
-- simple rings
--
function draw_ring(data)

    local value = data.value
    local value_max = data.value_max
    local bgc = data.bg_colour
    local bga = data.bg_alpha
    local fgc = data.fg_colour
    local fga = data.fg_alpha
    local xc, yc = data.x, data.y
    local radius = data.radius
    local thickness = data.thickness
    local sa = data.start_angle
    local ea = data.end_angle
    local lr = data.lr
    if value == nil then value=0  end
    local pct = value/value_max

    local angle_0 = sa * math.pi/180 - math.pi/2
    local angle_f = ea * math.pi/180 - math.pi/2
    local pct_arc = pct * (angle_f - angle_0)

    -- Draw background ring
    cairo_arc(cr, xc, yc, radius, angle_0, angle_f)
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, rgb_to_r_g_b(bgc, bga))
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, thickness)
    cairo_stroke(cr)

    -- Draw indicator ring
    cairo_arc(cr, xc, yc, radius, angle_0, angle_0 + pct_arc)
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, rgb_to_r_g_b(fgc, fga))
    cairo_stroke(cr)
end

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                              draw_gauge_bars
-- display gauge
--
function draw_gauge_bars(data)
    local x=data.x
    local y=data.y
    local divisions=data.divisions
    local div_width=data.div_width
    local div_height=data.div_height
    local div_gap=data.div_gap
    local br,bg,bb,ba=rgb_to_r_g_b(data.bg_color, data.bg_alpha)
    local sr,sg,sb,sa=rgb_to_r_g_b(data.st_color, data.fg_alpha)
    local mr,mg,mb,ma=rgb_to_r_g_b(data.mid_color, data.fg_alpha)
    local er,eg,eb,ea=rgb_to_r_g_b(data.end_color, data.fg_alpha)

    if data.value==nil then value=0 else value=data.value end

    local value_max=data.value_max
    local value_divs=(value/value_max)*divisions

    cairo_set_line_width (cr,div_width)

    for i=1,divisions do
        if i<(divisions/2) and i<=value_divs then
            colr=((mr-sr)*(i/(divisions/2)))+sr
            colg=((mg-sg)*(i/(divisions/2)))+sg
            colb=((mb-sb)*(i/(divisions/2)))+sb
            cola=((ma-sa)*(i/(divisions/2)))+sa
        elseif i>=(divisions/2) and i<=value_divs then
            colr=((er-mr)*((i-(divisions/2))/(divisions/2)))+mr
            colg=((eg-mg)*((i-(divisions/2))/(divisions/2)))+mg
            colb=((eb-mb)*((i-(divisions/2))/(divisions/2)))+mb
            cola=((ea-ma)*((i-(divisions/2))/(divisions/2)))+ma
        else
            colr=br
            colg=bg
            colb=bb
            cola=ba
        end

        cairo_set_source_rgba (cr,colr,colg,colb,cola)
        if data.orientation == "horizontal" then
            cairo_move_to (cr,x+((div_width+div_gap)*i-1),y)
        else
            cairo_move_to (cr,x,y-((div_width+div_gap)*i-1))
        end
        cairo_rel_line_to (cr,0,div_height)
        cairo_stroke (cr)
    end
end--function bars

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                         MAIN
function conky_main(color, theme, drawbg, unit, area_code, posfix)

    if conky_window == nil then return end

    local cs = cairo_xlib_surface_create(conky_window.display, conky_window.drawable, conky_window.visual, conky_window.width, conky_window.height)

    cr = cairo_create(cs)

    local updates=tonumber(conky_parse('${updates}'))
    if updates>5 then

    -- BACKGROUND COLOR
    if color == "white" then
        bgc = 0xffffff
        bga = 0.4
    else
        bgc = 0x1e1c1a
        bga = 0.8
    end

    local theme = ("0x" .. theme)
    local w = conky_window.width
    local h = conky_window.height
    local hori_space = w*0.07
    local vert_space = h*0.5
    local xp = hori_space
    local yp = vert_space

    -- BACKGROUND
    if drawbg == "on" then
    settings={
        x=0-1    , y=0 ,
        w=w+1    , h=h ,
        border=1 ,
        colour={{0,bgc,0.2},},
    };draw_box(settings)
    settings={
        x=0-1 , y=0 ,
        w=w+1 , h=h ,
        colour={{0.5,bgc,bga},{1,bgc,bga-0.1},},
        linear_gradient={0,0,w/2,h/2},
    };draw_box(settings)
    end

    -- APPEARANCE
    if color == "white" then
        bgc = 0x1e1c1a
        fgc = 0x1e1c1a
        bga = 0.15
        fga = 0.8
    else
        bgc = 0xffffff
        fgc = 0xffffff
        bga = 0.1
        fga = 0.8
    end

    settings = {--HOUR
        txt="88:88",
        x=(w/2)-140             , y=50          ,
        txt_weight=1        , txt_size=50,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc , txt_fg_alpha=bga ,
        font = "Digital Readout Thick Upright"
    };display_text(settings)
    settings = {--HOUR
        txt=conky_parse("${time %H:}"),
        x=(w/2)-140            , y=50          ,
        txt_weight=1        , txt_size=50,
        txt_fg_colour=theme , txt_fg_alpha=fga ,
        font = "Digital Readout Thick Upright"
    };display_text(settings)
    settings = {--MINUTES
        txt=conky_parse("${time %M}"),
        x=(w/2)-78             , y=50          ,
        txt_weight=1        , txt_size=50 ,
        txt_fg_colour=theme , txt_fg_alpha=fga ,
        font = "Digital Readout Thick Upright"
    };display_text(settings)

    if unit =='f' then
        unitChar = 'F°'
    else
        unitChar = 'C°'
    end

    settings = {--DAY TEMP
        txt="Temp: " .. get_yahoo_weather_info("cur", area_code, unit) .. unitChar,
        x=(w/2)+60               , y=20            ,
        txt_weight=0        , txt_size=12 ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc , txt_fg_alpha=fga    ,
    };display_text(settings)
    settings = {--DATA
        txt=conky_parse("${time %d}") .. " " .. conky_parse("${time %b}") .. " " .. conky_parse("${time %Y}"),
        x=(w/2)+60               , y=35            ,
        txt_weight=0        , txt_size=12 ,
        txt_fg_colour=theme , txt_fg_alpha=fga    ,
    };display_text(settings)
    settings = {--NAME WEEK
        txt=conky_parse("${time %A}"),
        x=(w/2)+60               , y=48           ,
        txt_weight=0        , txt_size=12 ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc , txt_fg_alpha=fga    ,
    };display_text(settings)

    settings = {--DAYS GRAPH
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${time %d}")),
        value_max=31               ,
        x=w/2                     , y=yp                        ,
        graph_radius=33            ,
        graph_thickness=5          ,
        graph_start_angle=215      ,
        graph_unit_angle=3.6       , graph_unit_thickness=2.6    ,
        graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
        graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
        hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
        txt_radius=42              ,
        txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
        graduation_radius=28       ,
        graduation_thickness=0     , graduation_mark_thickness=1 ,
        graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
        graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.4     ,
        caption=''                 ,
        caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
        caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
    };draw_gauge_ring(settings)

    settings = {--MONTHS GRAPH
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${time %m}")),
        value_max=12               ,
        x=w/2                     , y=yp                        ,
        graph_radius=33            ,
        graph_thickness=5          ,
        graph_start_angle=34       ,
        graph_unit_angle=9.2       , graph_unit_thickness=8.2    ,
        graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
        graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
        hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
        txt_radius=42              ,
        txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
        graduation_radius=28       ,
        graduation_thickness=0     , graduation_mark_thickness=1 ,
        graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
        graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.3     ,
        caption=''                 ,
        caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
        caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
    };draw_gauge_ring(settings)

    settings = {--SECONDS
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${time %S}")),
        value_max = 60    ,
        x = w/2          , y = yp          ,
        bg_colour = bgc   , bg_alpha = bga  ,
        fg_colour = theme , fg_alpha = fga  ,
        radius =25        , thickness = 10  ,
        start_angle = 0   , end_angle = 360 ,
        lr = 0            ,
    };draw_ring(settings)

    settings = {--CLOCK HANDS
        xc = w/2          ,
        yc = yp          ,
        colour = bgc     ,
        alpha = 1        ,
        show_secs = true ,
        size = 40        ,
    };clock_hands(settings)

    xp = ((w/2)/2.6) - posfix
    settings = {--CPU GRAPH CPU1
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${cpu cpu1}")),
        value_max=100              ,
        x=xp                       , y=yp                        ,
        graph_radius=22            ,
        graph_thickness=5          ,
        graph_start_angle=180      ,
        graph_unit_angle=2.7       , graph_unit_thickness=2.7    ,
        graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
        graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
        hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
        txt_radius=35              ,
        txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
        graduation_radius=28       ,
        graduation_thickness=0     , graduation_mark_thickness=1 ,
        graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
        graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.3     ,
        caption='CPU'              ,
        caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
        caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
    };draw_gauge_ring(settings)

    settings = {--CPU GRAPH CPU2
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${cpu cpu2}")) ,
        value_max=100              ,
        x=xp                       , y=yp                        ,
        graph_radius=17            ,
        graph_thickness=5          ,
        graph_start_angle=180      ,
        graph_unit_angle=2.7       , graph_unit_thickness=2.7    ,
        graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
        graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
        hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
        txt_radius=0               ,
        txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
        graduation_radius=28       ,
        graduation_thickness=0     , graduation_mark_thickness=1 ,
        graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
        graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.3     ,
        caption=''                 ,
        caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
        caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
    };draw_gauge_ring(settings)

    xp = xp + hori_space
    settings = {--MEMPERC GRAPH
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${memperc}")),
        value_max=100              ,
        x=xp                       , y=yp                        ,
        graph_radius=22            ,
        graph_thickness=5          ,
        graph_start_angle=180      ,
        graph_unit_angle=2.7       , graph_unit_thickness=2.7    ,
        graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
        graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
        hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
        txt_radius=0               ,
        txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
        graduation_radius=22       ,
        graduation_thickness=4     , graduation_mark_thickness=2 ,
        graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
        graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.5     ,
        caption='MEM'              ,
        caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
        caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
    };draw_gauge_ring(settings)

    xp = xp + hori_space
    settings = {--SWAP FILESYSTEM USED GRAPH
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${swapperc}")),
        value_max=100              ,
        x=xp                       , y=yp                        ,
        graph_radius=22            ,
        graph_thickness=5          ,
        graph_start_angle=180      ,
        graph_unit_angle=2.7       , graph_unit_thickness=2.7    ,
        graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
        graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
        hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
        txt_radius=0               ,
        txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
        graduation_radius=22       ,
        graduation_thickness=4     , graduation_mark_thickness=2 ,
        graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
        graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.5     ,
        caption='SWAP'             ,
        caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
        caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
    };draw_gauge_ring(settings)

    xp = w/2 + 170
    disks = {'/', '/home'}
    disksLabel = {'ROOT', 'HOME'}
    for i, partitions in ipairs(disks) do
        settings = {--ROOT FILESYSTEM USED GRAPH
            value=tonumber(conky_parse("${fs_used_perc " .. partitions .. "}")),
            value_max=100              ,
            x=xp                       , y=yp                        ,
            graph_radius=22            ,
            graph_thickness=5          ,
            graph_start_angle=180      ,
            graph_unit_angle=2.7       , graph_unit_thickness=2.7    ,
            graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
            graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
            hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
            txt_radius=0               ,
            txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
            txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
            graduation_radius=23       ,
            graduation_thickness=0     , graduation_mark_thickness=2 ,
            graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
            graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.5     ,
            caption=disksLabel[i]      ,
            caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
            caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
        };draw_gauge_ring(settings)
    end

    xp = xp + hori_space
    settings = {--NETWORK GRAPH DOWN
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${downspeedf wlan0}")),
        value_max=100              ,
        x=xp                       , y=yp                        ,
        graph_radius=22            ,
        graph_thickness=5          ,
        graph_start_angle=180      ,
        graph_unit_angle=2.7       , graph_unit_thickness=2.7    ,
        graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
        graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
        hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
        txt_radius=35              ,
        txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
        graduation_radius=28       ,
        graduation_thickness=0     , graduation_mark_thickness=1 ,
        graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
        graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.3     ,
        caption='NET'              ,
        caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
        caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
    };draw_gauge_ring(settings)

    settings = {--NETWORK GRAPH UP
        value=tonumber(conky_parse("${upspeedf wlan0}")),
        value_max=100              ,
        x=xp                       , y=yp                        ,
        graph_radius=17            ,
        graph_thickness=5          ,
        graph_start_angle=180      ,
        graph_unit_angle=2.7       , graph_unit_thickness=2.7    ,
        graph_bg_colour=bgc        , graph_bg_alpha=bga          ,
        graph_fg_colour=theme      , graph_fg_alpha=fga          ,
        hand_fg_colour=theme       , hand_fg_alpha=0.0           ,
        txt_radius=0               ,
        txt_weight=1               , txt_size=8.0                ,
        txt_fg_colour=fgc          , txt_fg_alpha=fga            ,
        graduation_radius=28       ,
        graduation_thickness=0     , graduation_mark_thickness=1 ,
        graduation_unit_angle=27   ,
        graduation_fg_colour=theme , graduation_fg_alpha=0.3     ,
        caption=''                 ,
        caption_weight=1           , caption_size=10.0           ,
        caption_fg_colour=fgc      , caption_fg_alpha=fga        ,
    };draw_gauge_ring(settings)

    end-- if updates>5
    cairo_destroy(cr)
    cairo_surface_destroy(cs)
    cr=nil
end-- end main function
```

Comment: Maybe you could still boil down you problem a bit? Eyballing all of your code might be asked to much to get answers on this one.

Comment: The problem was that I was getting no output from the 'NETWORK GRAPH' section of the script though there appeared to be no errors. I figured it out with help from the script developer; there were two copies of this script, and I was editing the wrong one. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was editing the wrong copy of the script.

This is embarrassing...